# Prove $\nabla\!\left(\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}\right) = -\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Prove $\nabla\!\left(\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}\right) = -\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^{3}}$

I was doing simple differentiation, and getting
$\nabla\!\left(\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}\right) = -{|\vec{r}|} ^{-2}\nabla{|\vec{r}|}$ what I am doing wrong as I need another $\vec{r}$ to get the power as 3?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your way?

Comment: thank you. Sure $\nabla(\frac{1}{\mod(\vec{r})}) = -{\mod({\vec{r})} ^{-2}}\nabla({\mod(\vec{r})})$

Comment: For gradients you also have as in the single variable case $$\nabla \left( \frac{f}{g} \right) = \frac{g \nabla f - f \nabla g}{g^2}.$$ This is because it holds in each component.  In your case we have something of the form $\nabla (1/g) = - (\nabla g )/ g^2.$ So now you only need to be able to compute $\nabla r$ which shouldn't be too hard. Edit: okay I didn't notice you already had that. Note that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ so to compute $\nabla r$ you should compute $\partial r / \partial x$ ; for $y$ and $z$ clearly give the same answer by symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{r}=
-\frac{1}{r^{2}}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x} r=
-\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=
$$
$$=-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{x}{r}=-\frac{x}{r^3}$$
For $y$ and $z$ we have the same, so:
$$\nabla \frac{1}{r}=\left(-\frac{x}{r^3},-\frac{y}{r^3},-\frac{z}{r^3}\right)^\top=
-\frac{1}{r^3}(x,y,z)^{\top}=-\frac{\textbf r}{r^3}$$

Comment: Thank you @Egor Ivanov

Answer (score 1):

$$
\nabla\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}
= -\frac{\nabla|\vec{r}|}{|\vec{r}|^2}
= -\frac{\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|}{|\vec{r}|^2}
= -\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}
$$